# Comma before "as" and "where"

Tags: commas

Can someone kindly help me determine if a comma is needed within the following two sentences?

1. It also challenged me to think creatively, as I frequently had to modify or reinvent traditional exercises in order to meet the needs of my target audience.
2. In 2016, I extended my passion for working with persons with developmental disabilities by embarking on a paid position working for The Ottawa General Hospital, where I supported teens with developmental disabilities.

Many thanks!